# SQL Query, one table, multiple conditions, multiple filters

Tags: sql

I am trying to reduce a db query by getting the results filtered...Not a SQL expert btw, my knowledge is limited to (SELECT * FROM table, along with a couple of joins etc.)

Anyways here's the question...I am doing a SELECT statement from a large table, which will return anywhere from 600k rows all the way up to 3million rows. Query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    (54 different columns) 
FROM table_001 
WHERE col_A > '1977987' AND (col_B BETWEEN '1000' AND '6000') 
      AND col_C < '2' AND (col_d BETWEEN '12345' AND 23456') 
      AND col_E != 'STUFF' AND col_F != 'STUFF' 
      AND (col_G = 'A1' OR col_G = '1001') 
      AND (col_H = 'B2' OR col_H = 'B3') 
ORDER BY col_d ASC;
```

When this query is run everything is satisfied up until the last 2 AND statements. I end up only getting results with col_G = '1001' and col_H= 'B3'.

If I take away the last 2 "AND" statements, things work just fine, I just have to export the dataset, then filter out the last 2 conditions in excel which is not as convenient.

Again I hope this makes sense as SQL is def not in my wheelhouse, but I figured there would be someone out here that could help out. I am sure there is a better way, just looking for some help!

Comment: Can you provide a sample row that you want returned but is not returned by this query? You don't need to list all 54 columns, but at least `col_g` and `col_h` and preferably all the columns used in the `where` clause.

Comment: so you haven't rows that satisfy the other OR condition. usually you start with one condition and add one by one and see what happens, especially when thn datasource is big.

Comment: @EdmCoff here's a sample row result:
....col_G....col_H....
....A1....Harris....
When the query says (col_G = '1001' OR col_G = 'A1') AND (col_H = 'Smith' OR col_H = 'Harris')

Comment: That example should work. https://dbfiddle.uk/bDaGW_iB Can you use the Fiddle I created as a starting point to add an actual example that fails?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you delete order by it will  be work?  You can use for 'union' instead of 'or' It should be worked better.

```
(
SELECT 
    (54 different columns) 
FROM table_001 
WHERE col_A > '1977987' AND (col_B BETWEEN '1000' AND '6000') 
      AND col_C < '2' AND (col_d BETWEEN '12345' AND 23456') 
      AND col_E != 'STUFF' AND col_F != 'STUFF' 
      AND (col_G = 'A1' ) 
      AND (col_H = 'B2' )
)
UNION      
(
SELECT 
    (54 different columns) 
FROM table_001 
WHERE col_A > '1977987' AND (col_B BETWEEN '1000' AND '6000') 
      AND col_C < '2' AND (col_d BETWEEN '12345' AND 23456') 
      AND col_E != 'STUFF' AND col_F != 'STUFF' 
      AND (col_G = '1001') 
      AND (col_H = 'B2' )
)
UNION      
(
SELECT 
    (54 different columns) 
FROM table_001 
WHERE col_A > '1977987' AND (col_B BETWEEN '1000' AND '6000') 
      AND col_C < '2' AND (col_d BETWEEN '12345' AND 23456') 
      AND col_E != 'STUFF' AND col_F != 'STUFF' 
      AND (col_G = 'A1') 
      AND (col_H = 'B3' )
)
UNION      
(
SELECT 
    (54 different columns) 
FROM table_001 
WHERE col_A > '1977987' AND (col_B BETWEEN '1000' AND '6000') 
      AND col_C < '2' AND (col_d BETWEEN '12345' AND 23456') 
      AND col_E != 'STUFF' AND col_F != 'STUFF' 
      AND (col_G = '1001') 
      AND (col_H = 'B3' )
)
UNION      
(
SELECT 
    (54 different columns) 
FROM table_001 
WHERE col_A > '1977987' AND (col_B BETWEEN '1000' AND '6000') 
      AND col_C < '2' AND (col_d BETWEEN '12345' AND 23456') 
      AND col_E != 'STUFF' AND col_F != 'STUFF' 
      AND (col_G = 'A1') 
      AND (col_H = 'B3' )
)

ORDER BY 4; -- (YOU HAVE TO PUT NUMBER OF COLUMN IN YOUR SELECT STATEMENT)
```